How to Customize Tooltip as component when on hovering of React AG Grid table(v 18 beta)
I am working on react ag grid table which is an older version (18 beta), as per the requirement and existing functionality i cannot update/migrate versions, so i want to create a custom tooltip when hovering on the table for one of the column Data Volume. for that i tried many but nothing works.
Can you please help me to create customized component based tool tip which will display the some information related to Data Volume.
This is what i tried but not working
Code:

CustomTooltip.js
import React from 'react';

const CustomTooltip = ({ value }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '10px', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)', color: 'white', borderRadius: '5px' }}>
      <p><strong>Data Volume:</strong> {value}%</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomTooltip;



2. MyAgGrid.js

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
    import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
    import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
    import CustomTooltip from './CustomTooltip';
    
    class MyAgGrid extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          columnDefs: [
            {
              headerName: 'Country',
              field: 'country',
              width: 170,
              cellStyle: { fontSize: '16px' },
            },
            {
              headerName: 'Severity',
              field: 'severity',
              width: 130,
              cellStyle: { fontSize: '16px' },
            },
            {
              headerName: 'Data Volume',
              field: 'dataVol',
              width: 210,
              tooltipComponent: 'customTooltip',
            },
            {
              headerName: 'Timestamp',
              field: 'timestamp',
              width: 150,
            },
          ],
          rowData: [
            { country: 'india', severity: 'High',  dataVol: 10,  timestamp: '2023-09-11' },
            { country: 'japan', severity: 'High',  dataVol: 1,  timestamp: '2023-09-10' },
            { country: 'china', severity: 'High',  dataVol: 0,  timestamp: '2023-09-09' },
          ],
          frameworkComponents: {
            customTooltip: CustomTooltip, 
          }
        };
      }
    
      render() {
        const { columnDefs, rowData, frameworkComponents } = this.state;
    
        return (
          <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: '400px', width: '600px' }}>
            <AgGridReact
              columnDefs={columnDefs}
              rowData={rowData}
              frameworkComponents={frameworkComponents}
              domLayout="autoHeight"
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default MyAgGrid;




What's not working? Is it not showing up?

tool tip not displaying while hovering on table cells

Please [edit] your question to include a minimal reproducible example so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

but i given the whole code right, you can see the tooltipComponent property for Data Volume Column definition which is not working, Can i know what are you expecting still?

I have created a very dynamic tooltip component using create portal and it can be triggered on hover or on click, also you can set the position of it (top, right, bottom, left)
react tooltip
How to use it:
<Tooltip tooltipContent="tooltip on <em>top</em>">
    <span className="underline">top</span>
 </Tooltip>

